# In Python (Windows 10) interpreter I am getting an 'invalid syntax' error for plt.show(). How do I rectify it?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a for loop:

```
for i in xrange(6):
    plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Here, `plt.show()` is giving me a syntax error:

[image: this is the error]

How do I rectify this error?

Comment: You haven't defined `plt`. Your code is incomplete. Don't post pictures of errors when you have it all as console output.

Comment: @Seth the image actually shows she defined it in the console. To the OP: please post the full code in the question and avoid posting images, since we can't then copy-paste the code to test it

Comment: >>> import cv2 as cv
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> img=cv.imread('gradient.png',0)
>>> ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
>>> ret,thresh2 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
>>> ret,thresh3 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_TRUNC)
>>> ret,thresh4 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_TOZERO)
>>> ret,thresh5 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
>>> titles = ['Original Image','BINARY','BINARY_INV','TRUNC','TOZERO','TOZERO_INV']
>>> images = [img, thresh1, thresh2, thresh3, thresh4, thresh5]

Comment: >>> for i in range(6):
...  plt.subplot(2,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
...  plt.title(titles[i])
...  plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
... plt.show()
  File "<stdin>", line 5
    plt.show()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>

Comment: @GPhilo, while generally speaking pasting the code is really what we want from OP and not screenshots, in this case the pasted code would have probably worked and it's the screenshot that shows the error which is due wrong usage of the interactive interpreter. Funny how these things work :)

Answer (score 1):

When using the interactive interpreter to define scopes (like the for loop you have), when you finished with the last line of the loop, you need another line (press enter on the keyboard) to finish writing the loop, this will cause the loop to be run, and only then can you write the next line.
When a line starts with ... it means you are still in the loop (or any other indented scope). only when it's back to >> you are out back to the normal indentation.

So what happened here, is that you are writing the plt.show line still in the loop but without the correct indentation. Which is a syntax error.

You might find it easier to write your code in a file and run that file using python, or to use some IDE. (but that's a whole different topic)

Comment: Even after pressing enter it is continuing with the same loop.(how do I exit the loop?)

Comment: @ApoorvaPanwal do you mean that after pressing enter the loop starts to run and you want to stop it, or do you mean that after enter you are still typing inside the loop (line starts with ...). For the second thing, again, after another enter you should be out of the loop typing and back to line starting with >>. If you are talking about stopping the run of the loop. Then that's a different question and you need to think about how you want to write you code and what you want to happen when.

Comment: I mean that even after pressing enter the line still starts with (...).Well I have tried pressing enter again and the line starts with>>> but passes the error saying "keyboard interruption".

Comment: "keyboard interruption" I think will be a different problem. it usually happens if you press ctrl+c or something like that to stop the code while it's running. But I don't know why it would happen to you in this case, it shouldn't happen from just pressing another enter to get out of the loop.